# XML at time of transfer parse what if we had Cascading Style Sheet in it?

Tags: css, xml, parsing, xslt

I need to ask that i have some XML and to style this i use Cascading Style Sheet/Extensible Style-sheet Language Transformations. I know XML data parse when it transfer, but now as i have Cascading Style Sheet/Extensible Style-sheet Language Transformations in it so will it still parse or interpret as Cascading Style Sheet is interpreting language.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking. Can you try to explain more, or show some examples of the XML, XSLT, and CSS that you're using?

Comment: i got the answer its very simple if we use css or xsl in our XML, then  XML won't parse it has to interpret for CSS or XSL.

Comment: I'm afraid your understand of "parsing" and "interpreting" isn't congruent with mine.

Comment: Don't afraid @ThomasW, Just correct me if I am wrong in something.

Comment: I can't really correct you because I don't quite get what you mean. Of course the XML will always be parsed by the browser (this is the process of reading a character stream and eventually turning it into a DOM), no matter if you associate a stylesheet or not.

Comment: @ThomasW Do you agree with the concept that css is the language that interpret, and xml is the language that parse?

Comment: No, the browser is the entity that parses and interprets. It parses both the XML and the CSS.

Comment: @ThomasW May b I am bit low in English that's why you can't get me properly. But I appreciate your help regarding my question. You are really helpful thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have CSS or XSL inside the XML (at least it won't render). You have to reference it using a processing instruction, like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" ?>
<thisIsYourDocument>
  some content
</thisIsYourDocument>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xsl" ?>
<thisIsYourDocument>
  some content
</thisIsYourDocument>
```

Comment: thanks for your help @Thomas W 
but after referencing css or xsl will parse or interpret?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand you correctly, but of course both the XML and the stylesheet will be parsed and "interpreted" (which means executed in the case of XSLT).

Comment: thanks very much for your cooperation.